# Finding the area under a quadrilateral whose sides are given by four linear equations.

Tags: coordinate-systems

Let there be $4$ equations, namely:

- $y=m_1x+c_1$
- $y=m_2x+c_2$
- $y=m_3x+c_3$
- $y=m_4x+c_4$

Assuming that these $4$ lines form a quadrilateral, how do I calculate the area of the quadrilateral?

One way I thought was that any quadrilateral can be made into two triangles by joining its opposite vertices.

Then I can calculate the areas of the individual triangles.

However that would be a long and tedious way.

Can there be a simple way?

Comment: To do this with variable $m_i$ and $c_i$ this is a heavy task, beginning with identifying the intended quadrilateral – there are several, and dozens of cases to consider. If the $m_i$ and $c_i$ are given numerically once and for all draw a figure. identify the quadrilateral you mean, and proceed with calculating the areas of the two triangles obtained by a dissection.

Comment: That is a possible way. But is it the only one?

Comment: No vertical lines allowed?  (After all, what would *m* be in that case?)

Answer (score 0):

If two pairs of lines are parallel then they will have an equal slope . Find intersection of points which intersect the lines at two points here let us assume $m_1||m_3$ and same for other two then find their points of intersections and then find distance between the three adjacent points by using distance formula.note its for quadrilatetals formed by two pairs of parallel lines. We also have formula for distance between parallel lines $\frac{|c_2-c_1|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ where $c_1,c_2$ are constants and $a,b$ are any arbitrary constants.

Comment: By your way, we will only find the perimeter of the quadrilateral. What if we want to find the area. The Distance Formula way is obvious and cumbersome. Can there be a universal way for this problem which will cover all quadrilaterals?

Comment: Area of rectangle is $l\times b$

Comment: Area of square $l^2$, paralleogram now if you want area for complex polygons then wikipedia would be a good source.

Comment: This site may help http://www.mathopenref.com/coordpolygonarea.html

Comment: That would qualify as a separate answer to the OP's question, @jbuddenh!  Please write it out in full and include more details, so that it is not a link-only answer.